# How to open "google my business" application from another app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

I can`t find how to open 'google my business' application from my own app. I can open instagram/facebook/pinterest/youtube etc but can't 'google my business'. Could someone help please with package name for android and query scheme for ios?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Google My Business profile URL ´https://g.co/[UNIQUE_BUSINESS_ID]´ is shortened and can't be available for a business owner to be shared.

Comment: what I need is only to open google my business application from my application. For android and ios. To open some web url is not a problem. The problem how to open application. Thank you